# Cannot plot contourf subplots using matplotlib and cartopy in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, cartopy

I am trying to plot 2 figures from NetCDF files after analysis into subplots, I could plot individually but cannot plot as subplots. There are no errors shown but figure not coming properly.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker

#%% OLR Import
fname ='/home/SIMS/P1/*.nc'                                              
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(fname)

olr = ds.olr
mea = ds.mean('time')

# OLR daily data import
cname ='/home/SIMS/olrr/OLR.nc'
dc = xr.open_dataset(cname)
colr = dc.olr

# calculating JJAS climatology 
def is_jjas(month):
    return (month >= 6) & (month <= 9)

seasonal_data_olr = colr.sel(time=is_jjas(colr['time.month']))
climatology = seasonal_data_olr.mean('time')
# Anomaly
anomaly_olr=mea-climatology



fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=80.0, min_latitude=-10.0, max_latitude=20.0, globe=None, latitude_true_scale=0.0))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
climatology.plot.contourf(ax=ax,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),vmin=0, vmax=245)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
anomaly_olr.olr.plot.contourf(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap="jet", vmin=-30, vmax=30)
plt.show()
```

my variables

climatology

> xarray.DataArray 'olr' (lat: 15, lon: 73)

anomaly_olr.olr

> xarray.DataArray 'olr' (lat: 15, lon: 73)

it gives this figure without contourf

[image: it gives this figure without contourf]

Comment: Can you please provide a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I have added more code. I could plot individually each plot, but cannot do as subplots.

Comment: @Keldorn you might not included the NetCDF files

Comment: I don't have the file because it is not a reproducible example.

Comment: @Keldorn any netCDF file will do, it is a simple subplot.
 I don't think it is so hard to reproduce. Anyway I have solved the issue and given my solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making few changes I could plot it well. I changed few lines as follows,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1, projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=80.0, min_latitude=-10.0, max_latitude=20.0, globe=None, latitude_true_scale=0.0))
anomaly_olr.olr.plot.contourf(ax=ax1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap="jet", vmin=-30, vmax=30)

ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2, projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=80.0, min_latitude=-10.0, max_latitude=20.0, globe=None, latitude_true_scale=0.0))
climatology.plot.contourf(ax=ax2,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),vmin=0, vmax=245)
plt.show()
```

Thanks anyway